# Query Waypoints need to scroll in both directions

Tags: infinite-scroll, jquery-waypoints

I am using [jQuery-waypoints and the infinite shortcut](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/infinite-scroll/) to load listings on my page. I have this all working and am trying to comply with [Google's Guidelines](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/02/infinite-scroll-search-friendly.html) on this by using pushState() to alter the browsers history. This is all working fine using this.

```
if ($('#list-col.active .list-col-content').length > 0 && !wayPoints) {
    initWaypoint();
}
;
function initWaypoint() {
    let infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
        element: $('#list-col.active .list-col-content'),
        offset: function () {
            return this.context.innerHeight() - this.adapter.outerHeight() + 2000
        },
        onAfterPageLoad: function (direction) {
            var last = $('.page-loaded:last');
            last.waypoint(function (direction) {
                if (direction == 'down') {
                    if (window[window.GoogleAnalyticsObject]) {
                        ga('set', 'page', last.data('url'));
                        ga('send', 'pageview');
                        console.log('pageview ' + last.data('url'));
                    }
                    history.pushState('', last.data('title'), last.data('url'));
                } else {
                    history.pushState('', last.data('prev_title'), last.data('prev_url'));
                }
            })
        }
    });
    wayPoints = true;
};
```

Here is my issue/questions.

The new browser's URL is now https://www.example.com/listingpage?page=15. Per Google's Guidelines, that "component page" needs to load content with page 15's listings, and only page 15's content. No problem, I can do that. But now I have an issue with the content BEFORE page 15.

**I now need to scroll up, loading more content (now above the existing content) as the user scrolls up.**

I am at a loss on how to add a second infinite (really finite since it is loading down to 0) scroller that loads pages as you scroll up the page.

I know I am not the first to encounter this so any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No responses in several days so I researched and found an answer on my own. Posting some info here in case anyone else has same issue with infinite scrolling in both directions.

Best solution I found was on Google's [Infinite Scroll search-friendly recommendations](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/02/infinite-scroll-search-friendly.html). That pages lists an [infinite scroll with pagination demo](http://scrollsample.appspot.com/items). I had to do some modification for my specific use, but it is a great example and obviously following Google's recommendation is a good way to go.

Hope this helps someone.